# How to read a matrix from a file in Chapel

Tags: sparse-matrix, chapel

This time I have a matrix --IN A FILE-- called "matrix.csv" and I want to read it in.  I can do it in two flavors, dense and sparse.

**Dense**

```
matrix.csv

3.0, 0.8, 1.1, 0.0, 2.0
0.8, 3.0, 1.3, 1.0, 0.0
1.1, 1.3, 4.0, 0.5, 1.7
0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.5
2.0, 0.0, 1.7, 1.5, 3.0
```

**Sparse**

```
matrix.csv
1,1,3.0
1,2,0,8
1,3,1.1
// 1,4 is missing
1,5,2.0
...
5,5,3.0
```

Assume the file is pretty large.  In both cases, I want to read these into a Matrix with the appropriate dimensions. In the dense case I probably don't need to provide meta-data.  In the second, I was thinking I should provide the "frame" of the matrix, like

```
matrix.csv
nrows:5
ncols:5
```

But I don't know the standard patterns.

== UPDATE ==

It's a bit difficult to find, but the [mmreadsp](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/master/test/modules/packages/matrixmarket/mm-read-sparse.chpl) can change your day from "Crashing the server" to "done in 11 seconds".  Thanks to Brad Cray (not his real name) for pointing it out!

Comment: Plus one for the narrative :o) "**I have a matrix**"! + Guess the sparse-matrix "frame" ( as a bounding-box ) will not help much, as the internal sparsity-representation & building / handling WRT non-zero elements during sparse-matrix operations ( traversing, inspection, addition, removal ) are most of all independent of the bounding-box per-se. Guess the best starting point would be to drill into Chapel source code inside modules, that create the sparse-matrix representations. That is a place to learn from as there ought be **no "Hic Sunt Leones"**, but the actual representation rules coded.

Comment: You need the frame to build the matrix.  It could happen that there are no values on the boundary of a sparse matrix.  The whole last column could be 0.

Comment: @BrianDolan - are you OK with the first line being: `rows, columns` for both sparse and dense case?

Comment: Yes, [matrix market format](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html) includes that. Let's start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preface

Since Chapel matrices are represented as arrays, this question is equivalent to:

"How to read an **array** from a file in Chapel".

Ideally, a `csv` module or a specialized IO-formatter (similar to [JSON formatter](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/modules/standard/IO/FormattedIO.html#general-conversions)) would handle `csv` I/O more elegantly, but this answer reflects the array I/O options available as of Chapel 1.16 pre-release.

### Dense Array I/O

Dense arrays are the easy case, since `DefaultRectangular` arrays (the default `type` of a Chapel array) come with a `.readWriteThis(f)` method. This method allows one to read and write an array with built-in `write()` and `read()` methods, as shown below:

```
var A: [1..5, 1..5] real;

// Give this array some values
[(i,j) in A.domain] A[i,j] = i + 10*j;

var writer = open('dense.txt', iomode.cw).writer();

writer.write(A);

writer.close();

var B: [1..5, 1..5] real;
var reader = open('dense.txt', iomode.r).reader();
reader.read(B);
reader.close();

assert(A == B);
```

The `dense.txt` looks like this:

```
11.0 21.0 31.0 41.0 51.0
12.0 22.0 32.0 42.0 52.0
13.0 23.0 33.0 43.0 53.0
14.0 24.0 34.0 44.0 54.0
15.0 25.0 35.0 45.0 55.0
```

However, this assumes you know the array shape in advance. We can remove this constraint by writing the array shape at the top of the file, as shown below:

```
var A: [1..5, 1..5] real;

[(i,j) in A.domain] A[i,j] = i + 10*j;

var writer = open('dense.txt', iomode.cw).writer();

writer.writeln(A.shape);
writer.write(A);

writer.close();

var reader = open('dense.txt', iomode.r).reader();
var shape: 2*int;
reader.read(shape);
var B: [1..shape[1], 1..shape[2]] real;
reader.read(B);
reader.close();

assert(A == B);
```

Now, `dense.txt` looks like this:

```
(5, 5)
11.0 21.0 31.0 41.0 51.0
12.0 22.0 32.0 42.0 52.0
13.0 23.0 33.0 43.0 53.0
14.0 24.0 34.0 44.0 54.0
15.0 25.0 35.0 45.0 55.0
```

### Sparse Array I/O

Sparse arrays require a little more work, because `DefaultSparse` arrays (the default `type` of a sparse Chapel array) only provide a `.writeThis(f)` method and not a `.readThis(f)` method as of Chapel 1.16 pre-release. This means we have builtin support for writing sparse arrays, but not reading them.

Since you specifically requested csv format, we'll do sparse arrays in csv:

```
// Create parent domain, sparse subdomain, and sparse array
const D = {1..10, 1..10};
var spD: sparse subdomain(D);
var A: [spD] real;

// Add some non-zeros:
spD += [(1,1), (1,5), (2,7), (5, 4), (6, 6), (9,3), (10,10)];

// Set non-zeros to 1.0 (to make things interesting?)
A = 1.0;

var writer = open('sparse.csv', iomode.cw).writer();

// Write shape
writer.writef('%n,%n\n', A.shape[1], A.shape[2]);

// Iterate over non-zero indices, writing: i,j,value
for (i,j) in spD {
  writer.writef('%n,%n,%n\n', i, j, A[i,j]);
}

writer.close();

var reader = open('sparse.csv', iomode.r).reader();

// Read shape
var shape: 2*int;
reader.readf('%n,%n', shape[1], shape[2]);

// Create parent domain, sparse subdomain, and sparse array
const Bdom = {1..shape[1], 1..shape[2]};
var spBdom: sparse subdomain(Bdom);
var B: [spBdom] real;

// This is an optimization that bulk-adds the indices. We could instead add
// the indices directly to spBdom and the value to B[i,j] each iteration
var indices: [1..0] 2*int,
    values: [1..0] real;

// Variables to be read into
var i, j: int,
    val: real;
while reader.readf('%n,%n,%n', i, j, val) {
  indices.push_back((i,j));
  values.push_back(val);
}

// bulk add the indices to spBdom and add values to B element-wise
spBdom += indices;
for (ij, v) in zip(indices, values) {
  B[ij] = v;
}

reader.close();

// Sparse arrays can't be zippered with anything other than their domains and
// sibling arrays, so we need to do an element-wise assertion:
assert(A.domain == B.domain);
for (i,j) in A.domain {
  assert(A[i,j] == B[i,j]);
}
```

And `sparse.csv` looks like this:

```
10,10
1,1,1
1,5,1
2,7,1
5,4,1
6,6,1
9,3,1
10,10,1
```

### MatrixMarket Module

Lastly, I'll mention that there is a `MatrixMarket` package module that supports dense & sparse array I/O using the [matrix market format](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html). This is currently not shown on the public documentation, because it is intended to be moved out as a standalone package once the package manager is reliable enough, but you can use it in your chapel programs with `use MatrixMarket;`, currently.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/master/modules/packages/MatrixMarket.chpl), which includes documentation for the interface as comments.

Here are the [tests](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/tree/master/test/modules/packages/matrixmarket), if you prefer to learn from example, rather than documentation & source code.

Comment: Does this `var shape: 2*int;` create a tuple?

Comment: Yep! The type `2*int` is a syntactic sugar for `(int, int)`.

Answer (score 0):

### A tribute to prof. Rudolf Zitny & prof. Petr Vopenka

[image]
 ( if one happens to remember the PC Tools utility, the Matrix Tools, pioneered and authored by prof. Zitny, were similarly indispensable for smart abstract-representations of large scale F77 FEM matrices, using `COMMON`-block and similar tricks for large and sparse-matrix efficient storage & operations in numerical-processing projects ... )

---

### Observation:

I cannot disagree more with the last remark on a need to have the "frame", so as to build a sparse matrix.

Matrix is always just an **interpretation** of some formalism.

While sparse-matrix share the same view on a matrix, as an *interpretation*, the implementation of each of such module is always strictly based on some concrete **representation**.

Different kinds of sparsity are always handled using different cells-layout-strategy ( the trick is to use a minimum-needed `[SPACE]` for cell-elements, while yet having some acceptable processing `[TIME]` overhead, when trying to perform classical matrix/vector operations on such matrix ( typically without user knowing or "manually" bothering with the underlying sparse-matrix representation, that was used for storing the cell values, and how is that being optimally decoded / translated into a target-sparse-matrix's representation ).

Put it visually, the Matrix Tools will show you each of the **representations** as compact as possible in their best-possible memory-layouts ( very like in the PC Tools it had compressed your Hard-Disk, laying sector-data so as to avoid any un-necessary non-contiguous HDD-capacity get wasted ) and the very ( type-by-type specific ) **representation**-aware handler will then provide any external observer the complete illusion, needed for an assumed matrix **interpretation** ( during the phase of computing ).

So let's realise first, that not knowing all the details about the platform-specific rules, used for a sparse-matrix **representation**, both on the source-side ( python-?, JSON-meta-payload-?, etc ) and on the [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) target-side ( **`LinearAlgebra`** ver-1.16 being yet confirmed not to be public ( W.I.P. ), there is not much to start to implement.

The actual **materialisation** of a ( yet un-known ) sparse-matrix **representation** ( be it a `file://`, a DMA-access or a CSP-channel or any other means of a Non-InRAM storage or an InRAM memory-map ) does not change the solution of cross-representation xlator a single bit.

As a matematician, you may enjoy the concept of **representation** being less a Cantor-set driven ( running into (almost) infinite, dense enumerations ) objects, but rather using Vopenka's Alternative Set Theory ( so lovely introduced with in-depth both historical and mathematical contexts in Vopenka's "Meditations About The Bases of Science" ) that has brought and polished much closer views on these very situations with a yet changing Horizon-of-Definition ( caused not only by an actual sharpness of observers view, but in a much broader and general sense of such a principle ), leaving pi-class and sigma-class semi-sets ready for continuous handling of emerging new details, as they come into our recognised part of the view ( once appearing "in front" of the Horizon-of-Definition ) about the observed ( and mathematicised ) phenomenon.

Sparse-matrices ( as a **representation** ) help us build the **interpretation** we need, so as to use the so far acquired data-cells in further processing "as a matrix".

### This said, the workflow always needs to know a-priori:

**a)** the constraints and rules used in the sparse-matrix source-system's **representation**
**b)** the additional constraints a mediation-channel imposes ( expressivity, format, self-healing/error-prone ) irrespective of it being a file, a CSP-channel or a ZeroMQ / nanomsg smart-socket signalling- / messaging-plane distributed agent infrastructure
**c)** the constraints and rules imposed in the target-system's **representation**, setting rules for defining / loading / storing / further handling & computing that a sparse-matrix type of one's choice has to meet / follow in the target computing eco-system

Not knowing the **a)** would introduce unnecessarily large overheads on preparing the strategy for both a successful and efficient cross-representation pipeline i.e. for translating the common **interpretation** from source-side **representation** for entering the **b)**. Ignoring the **c)** would always cause a penalty - to pay additional overheads in target-eco-system during the **b)**'s-mediated reconstruction of a communicated-interpretation onto the target-**representation**.